# String representation of React functions (Exactly as how we see them in a code editor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Say for example we have a function a follows:

```
function ParentWrappingDiv() {
    const temp = 5
    
    return(
        <div className="ParentWrapping">
            <h3>Parent Wrapping Div</h3>
            <State/>
            <Display/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Where State and Display are React functional components. So this function consists of js code (the const) and a JSX return element.

Usually to get a string representation of a function, you would do the following:

```
console.log(ParentWrappingDiv.toString())
```

However, when I try, it is showing a Pure object tree for the JSX element return:

```
function ParentWrappingDiv() {
  const temp = 5;
  return /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["jsxDEV"])("div", {
    className: "ParentWrapping",
    children: [/*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["jsxDEV"])("h3", {
      children: "Parent Wrapping Div"
    }, void 0, false, {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 74,
      columnNumber: 13
    }, this), /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["jsxDEV"])(_components_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["State"], {}, void 0, false, {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 75,
      columnNumber: 13
    }, this), /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["jsxDEV"])(_components_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["Display"], {}, void 0, false, {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 76,
      columnNumber: 13
    }, this)]
  }, void 0, true, {
    fileName: _jsxFileName,
    lineNumber: 73,
    columnNumber: 9
  }, this);
}
```

So you can see above the normal js code part is showing but the rest not the same.

Been busting my brain looking at libraries for aid. Found libraries that are able to return string representations of the return JSX element, but never the entire function. So the goal would like to get exact representation as it is coded:

```
function ParentWrappingDiv() {
    const temp = 5

    return(
        <div className="ParentWrapping">
            <h3>Parent Wrapping Div</h3>
            <State/>
            <Display/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Assume this function is contained within a js file alongside a functional component, in which I want to get the string representation of that function. Please help :(....

Comment: That's because Webpack transpiles your code, since regular JavaScript (as executed by e.g. the browser) doesn't support JSX, require/import, ... so I'm not entirely sure if this is possible. Neither am I sure why you actually need it?

Comment: You will need to download and parse the map files that React generates. Unfortunately this is a really big project which would take me the better part of several weeks to do and I can't afford to spend that much time to write a stackoverflow answer. You can see the specification of map files at: https://sourcemaps.info/spec.html

Comment: Sorry, just to give context. Am creating a React website for myself thats gonna act like a workbench for stuff to experiment on and learn React. So would like to be able to display the code bodies of functions next to their implementations shown on html. Don't want to create json/txt files inside the public folder and fetch it in the component to get the code string representation I need.

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately that's what you need to do. React automatically generate source maps unless you specifically hack your package.json to disable it. So there is nothing you need to do to generate source maps. You just need to download them and parse them. For example if you are debugging  `https://example.com/static/js/9.123a5567.chunk.js` you can download it's source map (the original source code string) at `https://example.com/static/js/9.123a5567.chunk.js.map`. If I were you I'd just use the developer console in my browser that alerady knows how to parse source maps

Comment: Also, React already comes with such a workbench. It's `npm start`. When you edit your code in an editor and save it you will automatically see the changes in your browser.

Comment: Think I confused a bit. So the site is not going to be interactive. Just gonna be like a tutorial site where you see an working implementation and code snippet next to it of the code used. So will be inserting features to the project itself Then when building and eventually hosting for myself, can just look at that site to see implementation + code used